# Flask-SqlAlchemy Error with ForeignKey for Tables in different Models.py files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create two tables, each from a different models.py file. There is a a foreign key link between the two tables.

I can get it to work correctly when the two classes below are in the same models.py file. However, when I put them in separate files I receive an errors.

How do I adapt this to so it works as expected? I can only find 1-to-many relationship examples where the tables in the same file.

Table 1 Code:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Person"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'example'}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person',
                                lazy='dynamic')
```

Table 2 Code:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Address"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'example'}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('example.Person.id'))
```

Error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'Address.person_id' could not find table 'example.Person' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Worked by importing the class before calling db.create_all()

ref: [Flask Sqlalchemy : relationships between different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720898/flask-sqlalchemy-relationships-between-different-modules)

Comment: This does not work for me.