# SQLAlchemy and Flask: NoReferencedTableError: Could not find table to associate with column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to learn Flask and SQLAlchemy off of a book, and I've gotten to a stage where I need to migrate the database (using `flask db migrate`).

I keep on running into this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'recip
e.user_id' could not find table 'user' with which to generate a foreign key to t
arget column 'id'
```

I've looked all over SO and found a lot of answers using `__tablename__` which I've already tried.

This is the code:

In recipe.py:

```
from extensions import db

recipe_list = []


def get_last_id():
    if recipe_list:
        last_recipe = recipe_list[-1]
    else:
        return 1
    return last_recipe.id + 1


class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200))
    num_of_servings = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cook_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    directions = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    is_publish = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
```

In users.py:

```
from extensions import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

    recipes = db.relationship('Recipe', backref='user')

    @classmethod
    def get_by_username(cls, username):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    @classmethod
    def get_by_email(cls, email):
        return cls.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

**Edit**

It was because my models were in two different files like JustCarlos commented. In order to solve the problem, I just imported both the models into my app.py.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_restful import Api

from Config import Config
from extensions import db
from models.recipe import Recipe
from models.user import User
from resources.recipe import RecipeListResource, RecipeResource, RecipePublic

def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

def register_resources(app):
    api = Api(app)
    api.add_resource(RecipeListResource, '/recipes')
    api.add_resource(RecipeResource, '/recipes/<int:id>')
    api.add_resource(RecipePublic, '/recipes/<int:id>/publish')

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    register_extensions(app)
    register_resources(app)

    return app



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: It's probably because you have your models in 2 separate files.                                           
Here is a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774553/flask-sqlalchemy-error-with-foreignkey-for-tables-in-different-models-py-files

Comment: It might be flask migrate trying to migrate Recipe model before User model. Can you post your models.py?